# getting code coverage to 100% - try except pass -> with suppress

Tags: python, exception, code-coverage, pytest, contextmanager

I'm puzzled by pytest and was wondering if anyone knows what's going on.

I was trying to get code coverage of a project to 100%. 
The 2 lines that were missing were, the except and pass part of a try-except-pass:

```
> USER, PASS = None, None
> try:
>     from secrets import USER, PASS
! except ImportError:
!     pass
```

I changed it to:

```
with suppress(ImportError):
    from secrets import USER, PASS
```

and now the import is covered by my tests(?) even though I did not add any tests.

Why? What's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

Because you have removed the `except` block. Coverage just checks the lines of your code and because obviously you have test which doesn't raise an `ImportError` when reaches this part of your code and executes it successfully. And `coverage` counts these as covered.

Comment: I've have a similar situation, however while I do have a test which does raise the `Error` and the `except` line is marked as covered, the `pass` statement within the `except` block still remains uncovered. Seems strange.